# How Not to Pull Data From Firebase at Every Startup of the App #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an app for a gym which shows gym members info in a recyclerview at the app startup , the problem is **at every fresh launch of the app the data is pulled from the firebase database** and appears suddenly after 4-5 seconds in the recyclerview after the app starts, and i think this time will increase as the data grows.

If the data is same why pull it every time.

But i want to go one step further

what i want is when the user logs in for the first time all the data liked to that account should get pulled off and stored locally , i don't want to pull the data ever again even if the user is connected to internet, the changes user make should be made to realtime database as well as locally regardless how much data is created , so that i never need to pull data again once the user is logged in but just push the data every time it changes or grows or gets deleted, operations will happen to both local storage as well as at realtime database, so the user will always have local access to data he created.

And if he logs in again same thing happen again.

Is there a way to do it with firebase without implementing local sqlite database together with firebase realtime database.

Comment: Sure, this sounds like something you can code up.  It's not going to be just a few lines of code, and you're probably going to end up using a local database for it.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes doug i can use sqlite databse, but i want to know does firebase sdk provides that kind of functionality to do it automatically , like they they do with firebase offline support

Comment: If you *never want to pull the data again*, what's the purpose of storing and updating it in the cloud, since you'll never need it.

Comment: @Jay i can pull it in the next login, but not as long as the user is logged in

Comment: That statement doesn't agree what what's in your question so it's a little confusing what's being asked. Your question states *the problem is at every fresh launch of the app the data is pulled from the firebase database* which is stating the issue occurs when the user logs in. But your above comment says *i can pull it in the next login* which is the opposite. Perhaps clarifying the question may lead to an answer.

Comment: @Jay i was not talking about a problem i was talking about the default behavior of firebase app , when i launch the app the valueEventListener is executed and i get the data , and if i close the app and start again the same thing happens again but the data is still the same i don't want to pull it again, so i need an advice about how to store that data which is pulled once and don't pull it again. But now i got a solution tell me if it is correct , so when the user logs in i am pulling all of his data and storing locally , and when data changes i push it , and user only sqlite data in app.

Comment: Ok, let's try this: You're stating that if the data is the same, from last login, you don't want to pull it again. How would you know if the data is the same without comparing the data on the server to the local data? Keep in mind that only you know your app, we have no other information than what you provide us.

Comment: right, but it is a list of members most of times a member is not deleted and his detail like name, address, phone number does not change so was trying to avoid download data every , so i thought of using sqlite and use firebase to just sync the data moreover it was make app work offline, if i don't do that , it always take few seconds to load that data from realtime database which i don't want, now i have a solution , thanks for your time Jay

Comment: also the members will also have photos in their profile, at every launch if i was going to download images i would have take lot of time and like like if i have 100 members then i photo is 1 mb that is 100 md download at every launch resulting a huge billing

Comment: Here's the issue **most of times a member is not deleted** which indicates sometimes it is. So how would determine if it was or not without comparing your local data to what's on the server? Also, if you're app is crafted correctly, you would not download 100 users images - you would only download enough to populate your UI and then paginate your data as the user moves through it. Additionally, while a photo *could* be 1Mb that's a pretty large photo - most apps use thumbnails which are a few k of data and only download full size images when they are being edited.

Comment: yes jay you're right, i implemented , when the user logs in i am pulling all or his data in sqlite database and after that whenever he makes any changes in push to firebase realtime database also to sqlite , so just pusing no pulling as long as the user in logged in, if user logs out i need to clear data because maybe he will login with another account now, and if he logs in with same account , his all data is already there becasue i was pusing it, now again i will pull it all and load in local sqlite and this process will keep repeating , all reading is done from local database it's fast too.

Comment: still need to some work done, tell me if there are other good ways , thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for a use case where data is stored locally as well as on a remote server - similar to what's in the question. It may not specifically answer the question but may lead to a solution.

In the question, it appears there's local data and remotely stored data which are essentially the same - the OP is using sql to store locally and Firebase to store remotely. This is being done to 'speed up' the loading process and lower the amount of reads.

My suggestion is to use Firebase only. It's very fast and if coded correctly, the loading time should never be 4-5 seconds before the UI is available to the user (barring a bad internet connection if not using persistence).

Additionally, Firebase offers locally persisted data in two ways; cached data and persisted data (which are similar but read on)

> Cached: Firebase apps automatically handle temporary network interruptions.
>   Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes
>   when network connectivity is restored.

and

> Persisted: By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database
>   client would sync while online persists to disk and is available
>   offline, **even when the user or operating system restarts the app**. This
>   means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored
>   in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for local
>   updates.

There's a lot more to it so please see [iOS Offline Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) and [Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Comment: You understood it right Jay , as you said loading time can be decreased i will look for ways of doing this but still the reads will be the same means more downloading , which sqlite prevents me from , because if user is online he  will be pulling the data , can i do something so that he use cached data even when online hence decrease in reads , also then  I can remove sqlite which is making it more complex.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan If you're review my answer, Firebase offers persistence, so even when the app is restarted, it's using local data. Keep in mind also that Firebase is only going to download data when something is added, changed or removed from the database - other than that it can used cached data unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: so if i have 100 records and one of them is changed or one is added it will download the one only when the user is online , so no unnecessary reads, is it going to user cache as a database and it will grow with data ? then why doug stevens from firebase suggested me to implement it myself, see his answer

Comment: Read this [Key Capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database#key_capabilities). *every time data changes, any connected device receives that update* and then *Once connectivity is reestablished, the client device receives any changes it missed, synchronizing it* and then **By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app**. I believe his answer was because the use case presented in the question was/is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions suggests that the Firebase SDKs provides this sort of functionality.  It does not.  You will have to implement something yourself.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to tackle this in an easy and the most efficient way is to use the Room Persistence provided by AndroidX Architecture.

It is technically an ORM over SQLite. Please find the details here:
[AndroidX Room Persistence](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk92x4Zya6AIVCOh3Ch3mxQ2qEAAYASAAEgIcPvD_BwEAgQEAE&adurl=)